# Flutter iOS build error with Android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio

App is not running in Android studio but app is running if I open iOS project from Xcode.

There is a function which call iOS native function using (FlutterMethodCall) So in that case I have to add external pod to Runner project.

Note :
I have externally added some of pods also.

[image: pod]

Please help me to solve this.
[image: Android console]

Comment: Please add some more details on what & how you've added pods externally. 
From where this ObjectMapper coming from.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this,

get "Runner.xcodeproj" from git history and regenerate "Runner.xcworkspace".